# How to change password using recovery console?

Tags: login, password

Im having a problem entering my password in the login, every time i login its says thats wrong. Can I change it via recovery console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the password of a given user, just use the `passwd` command. For example, if I wanted to change the password of **admin**, I would use this command:

```
sudo passwd admin
```

I hope I helped :)